# How do I assign an array element in a 2D array to a variable?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

```
int board[4][8] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
    {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
};

int secondRow[8] = board[1]; // <-- error: invalid initializer

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (someCondition(secondRow[i])) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I assign the second element in `board` (the `{1, 2, ..., 7, 8}` array) to `secondRow`?
Do I declare `secondRow` as a pointer of some sorts instead? If so, can I still use it in the same way in the loop below (or how should I change it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You must either **copy** it or **reference** it.

You probably want the latter:

```
int * secondRow = board[1];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (someCondition(secondRow[i]))
        ...
}
```

Arrays are not first class citizens in C and C++.

Comment: the line `int * secondRow = board[1];`  gives: `warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

Comment: @vocusyson that message indicates your real code is different to what you posted in the question

Comment: thanks, I had `const int board[4][8] = {` (but somehow left it out in the question) and thus needed to do `const int * secondRow = board[1];` instead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for but if you are already looping through secondRow[i] why not assign values as you go?

```
int secondRow[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    secondRow[i]=board[1][i]; //Here
    if (someCondition(secondRow[i])) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, but this doesn't answer how `secondRow` should be declared in the first place

Comment: Yeah I just suggested this as you initially seemed to have trouble with Dúthomhas's answer. Glad everything works now though.